# Cannot see navigation gutter for IntelliTrace in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellitrace

I have VS2019 Enterprise version and am following this example [Intellitrace debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/historical-debugging-inspect-app?view=vs-2019). I have enabled Intellitrace:

[image: Intellitrace options]

and have set the option to display the navigation gutter:

[image]

But when i'm debugging i don't see the expected double arrows in the margin:

[image]

Any ideas why i'm not seeing them ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this feature is (rather surprisingly) only supported for .net framework projects and not .net core [Intellitrace does not work with .NET Core](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Intellitrace-does-not-work-with-NET-Cor/59746?space=8&q=Intellitrace&viewtype=solutions)